# virtual hosts alias and php include

Tags: php, html, apache

I am currently having a problem since I need to use Alias in my virtual host.

This is my Alias-Config:

```
Alias /projects/proj_one/core /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/projects/core
```

So when I am within `proj_one` it **works** when I simply use HTML like `<img 'src=core/..'>`

However when I want to use `<?php require_once('core/file.php') ?>`
it tells me that the file wasn't found: `failed to open stream: No such file or directory in`

So I think that php does just look for `core/` within the project and doesn't obviously find it, since it doesn't understand that Alias from virtual host.

How can I tell php that this file is somewhere else through Alias?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The virtual host alias is for apache and not for php.
When you require or include a file you should use.

```
require_once(__DIR__.'/core/file.php');
```

if the directory core is in the directory where your file in which you are including exists.

Where `__DIR__` is always the current directory.

So let us say you call require in your index.php and your project structure is:

```
/home/apps/application
           |-index.php
           |-core
               |-file.php
```

Then this code:

```
require_once(__DIR__.'/core/file.php');
```

will work.

If your structure is:

```
/home/apps/application
           |-public
           |   |-index.php
           |-core
               |-file.php
```

Then :

```
require_once(__DIR__.'/../core/file.php');
```

This will work.

Comment: Well yes i was mistaken, I was actually thinking that I can't access the file outside vhost with PHP, because I can't do it with HTML and JavaScript, since it's probably client-sided. Thank you very much though !

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this error:

```
"failed to open stream: No such file or directory in"
```

is that you used a relative path, not absolute in:

```
"require_once('core/file.php')";
```

Just use absolute path and everything would work.

```
require_once(__DIR__.'/core/file.php');
```